# How to deploy or delete several virtual machines at once with Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

How can I do multiple operations on multiple VM's like creating or deleting 10 VM's through Azure PowerShell scripts?

Comment: You might want to add a little bit more information for someone to give you a good response.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we deploy a bunch of VMs in order to increase the availability and reliability of Virtual Machine solutions on Azure using [Availability Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-availability-sets#availability-set-overview) or manage a set of identical, auto-scaling virtual machines using [virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-create-vmss#scale-set-overview).

In this case, if you just want to deploy a volume of VMs once time. You can use a **for** loop with powershell. For example, you create two VMs as following steps:

1. Create a resource group

   `New-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupVM" -Location "EastUS"`
2. Create 2 VMs using FOR loop.

   ```
        for ($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++)
   {
       $cred = Get-Credential
       New-AzureRmVm `
           -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupVM" `
           -Name "myVM$i" `
           -Location "East US" `
           -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
           -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
           -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" `
           -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress$i" `
           -Credential $cred
   }
   ```
3. Remove your resource group to remove VMs.

   `Remove-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name "ResourceGroupVM" -Force`

However, it is recommended to use the [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/ps-template) to deploy many independent VMs. You can create a template file that deploys the resources and a parameters file that supplies parameter values to the template. Then deploy the template. Using template is a more flexible method to deploy many personalized VMs that you can specific lots of properties (e.g. virtual network, subnet, load balancer configs, etc.)

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: Hi Xiong,
I was trying to exicte This ,But am getting following error can you please help me

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> for ($i=1; $i -le 2; $i++)

Missing statement body in for loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingLoopStatement

Comment: Save the full For loop as a .ps1 file, and place it on the desktop. then locate at the file path to execute the powershell script. For example,  `PS C:\windows\system32> C:\Users\nancyx2\Desktop\qaz.ps1`.

Comment: Is it possible to remove and stop Vm using this script.... And can you please share how to stop scduled shut down... Like I want to stop at Saturday and Sunday is it possible.... Please help me xiong

Comment: It is complicated to remove VM using the script because of one VM has attached resources like disks, nic, nsg, storage account ...etc. It is strongly recommended to remove related resources groups if you do remove many VMs. If you really need this script, you may refer to [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/delete-an-azure-vm-with-objects-using-powershell/).  About stoping sceduled job, you can have a look at [automation account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management).

Comment: You can use this command to remove only VM `Remove-AzureRmVM -Name $myVM1 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupVM -Force`